# How to get Apache to serve new css file in Rails development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, caching

I finally moved to using a Linux based development server for Rails, via VirtualBox.  I'm using a pre-built image that includes Apache and Passenger.

Everything is great, except Apache still tries to serve an older version of css files in development mode.  Even restarting the server doesn't work.  I've tried clearing the browser cache as well.  Since everything worked fine before Apache I'm guessing this is an Apache issue.  Do any experts know how to fix this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I apparently left out a crucial piece of information- I am using a shared folder with virtualbox.  Apparently this causes problems with css files (although rails does not get cached).

You need to change apache config see here: http://cantuse.it/2009/01/virtualbox-apache2-strange-caching-issues/) - add EnableMMAP Off EnableSendfile Off to your config file.  Thanks amphibient for looking into this, I just missed the important info :S

Answer (score 0):

unless you're doing something unnatural (which it doesn't sound like) apache will only server files that are 1) available to it & 2) requested.

have you updated your file that calls/includes the CSS file?

have you tried a different browser? - if only to be "sure"...

Comment: I have tried Chrome, IE and Firefox, all the same.  Clearing the browser cache doesn't help.  I can get it to refresh if I rename the file, request the file, rename back to original name, and request again.

Comment: what is config.action_controller.perform_caching set to in your config/environments/development.rb?

also, you may have to clear out public/stylesheets/cached

Comment: perform_caching is set to false.  I don't have a cached folder under stylesheets.